# Continuously update from Api

Tags: c#, maui

I am developing a meeting app, using Daily API (https://www.daily.co/)

The problem is that when I load a meeting, I arrive on the lobby, therefore, the `ongoing` is false that is part of the json response.

For example, I am not in the meeting, therefore.

```
"data": [{
        "id": "f10fde3f-4e7a-49e4-8018-dabc51409e8f",
        "room": "Programming101",
        "start_time": 1708360638,
        "duration": 45,
        "ongoing": false, // this is what I need to keep track on
```

If I enter the meting

```
{
    "total_count": 52,
    "data": [{
        "id": "bc4c5439-60ef-47cb-a8bf-6970529dc9ab",
        "room": "Programming101",
        "start_time": 1708361511,
        "duration": 5,
        "ongoing": true, // this is what changes.
        "max_participants": 1,
        "participants": [{
```

So, in order to keep track of the `ongoing` I need to make call every X second, to see if the value has change to `true` meaning that I enter the meeting.

I have a service.

```
 public async Task<object> GetMeetingData(string roomName, string authToken) {

     string apiUrl = $"https://api.daily.co/v1/meetings?room={roomName}";

     var data = await httpService.GetAsync<MeetingData>(apiUrl, authToken);

     return data!;
 }
```

and in my viewModel, I created with a timer, a method to start the polling and to get the data.

```
public async Task InitializeApiPolling() {
    StartMeetingApiPolling();
    await UpdateMeetingData();
}
private void StartMeetingApiPolling() {
    apiRequestDataTimer = new Timer(
        async state => await GetMeeetingData(),
        null,
        TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    );
}
private void StartBreakTimeTimer() {
    breakTimeTimer = new Timer(
        state => ShowAlert(new BreakTimePopUp()),
        null,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}
private void StartMeetingTimer() {
    stopwatch!.Start();
    meetingTimer = new Timer(state => UpdateElapsedTime(),
        null,
        TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
private void UpdateElapsedTime() {
    TimeSpan elapsed = stopwatch!.Elapsed;
    ElapsedTimeString = $"{elapsed.Hours:D2}:{elapsed.Minutes:D2}:{elapsed.Seconds:D2}";
}
private async Task UpdateMeetingData() {
    if(data == null) {
        data = (MeetingData?)await meetingService.GetMeetingData(RoomName, Constants.DAILY_AUTH_TOKEN);
    }
    await GetMeeetingData();
    ; // Trigger data processing
}
private async Task VerifyAddressAsync(IAppService appService) {
    if(Text is not null && Text!.Contains("demy-ia")) {
        GotoSite();
    } else {
        await appService.DisplayAlert("Error", "Please paste a valid meeting link", "OK");
    }
}
private async void GotoSite() {
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)) {
        IsWebViewVisible = true;
        if(IsWebViewVisible) {
            ToolbarVisibility = !ToolbarVisibility;
            MeetingSearchVibiility = !MeetingSearchVibiility;
            appShell.FlyoutWidth = 0;
            StartBreakTimeTimer();
            await InitializeApiPolling();
            StartMeetingTimer();
        }
    }
}
private async Task GetMeeetingData() {
    if(data != null) {
        var meetingData = data;
        bool isOngoing = meetingData!.data[0].ongoing;
        if(isOngoing is false) {
            await appService.DisplayAlert(Title, "you are in the lobby", "OK");
        } else if(isOngoing is true) {
            await appService.DisplayAlert(Title, "you are in the meeting", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

but when it, the `ongoing` variable is always false.

if you read the doc (https://docs.daily.co/reference/rest-api/meetings/get-meeting-information)

```
The optional ongoing argument is a boolean value. If set to true, it limits results to meetings where participants are currently in the room. If set to false, it limits the results to meetings where there are no participants remaining in the room.
```

this is my interface and service

```
    public async Task<string> CreateMeetingAsync(string roomName, MeetingOptions meetingOptions, string authToken) {

        string apiUrl = "https://api.daily.co/v1/rooms/";

        try {

            var room = new Room { Name = roomName, Privacy = "public", meetingOptions = meetingOptions };

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(room);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await httpService.PostAsync(apiUrl, content, authToken);

            if(response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<RoomResponse>();
                return responseContent?.url!;

            } else {
                var statusCode = response?.StatusCode;
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", response!.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, "OK");
                return string.Empty;
            }

        } catch(Exception) {

            return string.Empty;

        }
    }

    public async Task<object> GetMeetingData(string roomName, string authToken) {

        string apiUrl = $"https://api.daily.co/v1/meetings?room={roomName}";

        var data = await httpService.GetAsync<MeetingData>(apiUrl, authToken);

        return data!;
    }
}

    Task<object> GetMeetingData(string roomName, string authToken);
```

**update**

I just put this method in

````
   private Task GetMeeetingData() {
       if(data != null) {
           var meetingData = data;
           bool isOngoing = meetingData!.data[0].ongoing;
           if(isOngoing) {
               Debug.WriteLine("I am not in the meeting");
           } else {
               Debug.WriteLine("I am in the meeting");
           }
       }```
but I always get that I am in the meeting
````

Comment: which specific line causes the exception?

Comment: here

 await appService.DisplayAlert(Title, "you are in the lobby", "OK");

I dont undestand the first tie runds correcly, but it dosent update

Comment: try using `MainThread` when calling it

Comment: I can use that, but that was only for debugging, the real issue is that even thou I enter the meeting it dosent update.

Comment: then you need to [edit] your question to make it clearer what the actual problem you need help with is

Comment: Any kind of polling is a bad use of resources.  A well defined API will use push notifications, either via SignalR, or a Web Hooks, or some other kind.   Continually polling is not recommended (most of your calls will say 'nothing to do' which is a waste), of bandwidth, processor time, and other resources.

Comment: well, this is their Api, so I do not have any control over that, but the question is why Is not updating

Comment: have you verified that `MeetingData` is getting deserialized correctly?

Comment: Does the API really respond with two different data shapes depending on if the meeting is ongoing or not? How does your code handle this?

Comment: THE THIING IS, THAT WHEN I DEBUG, THE VALUE OF ONGOING IS ALWAYS FALSE

Comment: I just put this method in

```
   private Task GetMeeetingData() {
       if(data != null) {
           var meetingData = data;
           bool isOngoing = meetingData!.data[0].ongoing;
           if(isOngoing) {
               Debug.WriteLine("I am not in the meeting");
           } else {
               Debug.WriteLine("I am in the meeting");
           }
       }```
but I always get that I am in the meeting

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Where do you update the value of the variable `ongoing`?

Comment: when I enter the meeting, the value of `ongoing` should change to true, that is why I check every x second, to see if the user enters the meeting. If the user is in the meeting, `ongoing` is true, if not is false. I already try to enter a dummy meeting and the value is doesn't change. https://docs.daily.co/reference/rest-api/meetings/get-meeting-information

Comment: Have you checked if the actual data for the variable  `ongoing ` has changed?

Comment: Omg, I just realize that I am checking with the same data. When I check it, I need to call the api again and tell it to give me a fresh data. The question that I have now is how would that impact performance, becouse I am constantly calling the api for new data

Comment: It will affect a little bit to a greater or lesser extent, and it may depend on whether your design is efficient or not.